# Is it possible to represent an infinite triangle using barycentric coordinates?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

I want to find the coordinates of the elements in an infinitely extending triangle, and I stumbled upon barycentric coordinates, which are used to represent points with respect to a triangle. However, I don't know if it is possible to apply them to these constructions, as they only have one vertex. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

(By infinitely extending triangles, I mean something similar to Pascal's triangle)